# Resize tikzfigure in tcolorbox depending on height of tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, calculations, tcolorbox

in my book I got many different type of boxes so I made some macros placing the boxes automatically according to their arguments. [image]

That's one of them. So far I made some boxes that have big "+" and "-" inside and some that have small ones. It'd be nice, if I could manage to adapt the size of the signs according to the height of the box.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{mp}{RGB}{240,240,240} 

\newcommand{\bround}{
                    \draw[rounded corners=15pt,color=mp,line width=1pt,fill=white]
                        (frame.south west) -- 
                        (frame.north west) -- 
                        (frame.north east) --
                        (frame.south east) -- cycle;
}
\newcommand{\sep}{
                    \draw[color=mp,line width=1pt]
                    ([yshift=10pt]segmentation.south) -- ([yshift=-10pt]segmentation.north);
}

\newcommand{\ds}[1]{
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
                {bpl}{\dosign{0.25}{x}{y}{0}{0}{20}{-50}{50}{-60}}%
                {bmr}{\dosign{0.75}{x}{x}{0}{0}{20}{-50}{50}{-60}}%
    }[\PackageError{ds}{Undefined option to ds: #1}{}]%
}

\newcommand{\dosign}[9]{
                \coordinate (xl) at ($ (frame.west)!#1!(frame.east) $ );
                \coordinate (yl) at ([yshift=#9pt] $ (frame.north)$ ); 
                    \draw[line width=#6pt,mp]
                        ([#2shift=#7pt,yshift=#4pt]xl|-yl) -- ([#2shift=#8pt,yshift=#4pt]xl|-yl);  
                    \draw[line width=#6pt,mp]
                        ([#3shift=#7pt,yshift=#5pt]xl|-yl) -- ([#3shift=#8pt,yshift=#5pt]xl|-yl);
}

\newcommand{\doibs}[4]{\scantokens{%
            \begin{tcolorbox}[   
                    colback=white,
                    arc=10pt,
                    colframe=black,
                    freelance,
                    sidebyside,
                    sidebyside align=top,
                    frame code=\bround,
                    segmentation code=\sep,
                    interior code=\ds{#3}\ds{#4}
            ]
            \raggedright #1 \tcblower \raggedright #2
            \end{tcolorbox}}}

\begin{document}

\doibs{A\\A\\A\\A}{B}{bpl}{bmr}

\end{document}
```

As I have every type of combination (+-,++,--,+=,==,..), I wrote those macros keeping the source code as minimal as possible (according to my skills).
If I had the possibility to get the height in macro `\ds`, I could ajust the signs by recalculating their dimensions, coordinates, etc.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Do you want just the height/widht of the symbols to adapt or also the line width used for the symbols?

Comment: they should be stretched proportional, therefore the line width as well

Comment: I thought so. The second solution in my answer below also adjusts the line width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Updated version:

The first version of the code (see below) had one problem: if the box height was too big, then the signs will protrude their corresponding boxes; this can be solved choosing a maximum value for the length of the signs. The following code shows one such possibility; the length is (approximately) the minimum between the height of the box and half its width:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=30cm,textheight=25cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{mp}{RGB}{240,240,240} 

% To control the line width for the signs
\def\RuleFactor{0.15}

\newcommand{\bround}{
                    \draw[rounded corners=15pt,color=mp,line width=1pt,fill=white]
                        (frame.south west) -- 
                        (frame.north west) -- 
                        (frame.north east) --
                        (frame.south east) -- cycle;
}
\newcommand{\sep}{
                    \draw[color=mp,line width=1pt]
                    ([yshift=10pt]segmentation.south) -- ([yshift=-10pt]segmentation.north);
}

\newcommand{\ds}[1]{
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
                {pp}{\dosign{0.25}{plus}\dosign{0.75}{plus}}%
                {pm}{\dosign{0.25}{plus}\dosign{0.75}{minus}}%
                {pe}{\dosign{0.25}{plus}\dosign{0.75}{equal}}%
                {mp}{\dosign{0.25}{minus}\dosign{0.75}{plus}}%
                {mm}{\dosign{0.25}{minus}\dosign{0.75}{minus}}%
                {me}{\dosign{0.25}{minus}\dosign{0.75}{equal}}%
                {ep}{\dosign{0.25}{equal}\dosign{0.75}{plus}}%
                {em}{\dosign{0.25}{equal}\dosign{0.75}{minus}}%
                {ee}{\dosign{0.25}{equal}\dosign{0.75}{equal}}%
    }[\PackageError{ds}{Undefined option to ds: #1}{}]%
}

\newcommand{\dosign}[2]{
                    \coordinate (xl) at ($ (frame.west)!#1!(frame.east) $ ); 
\IfEq{#2}{plus}{%
                    \path[mp,draw]
                        let \p1 = ( $ ([yshift=-5pt]xl|-frame.north) - ([yshift=5pt]xl|-frame.south) $ ),
                              \p2 = ( $ ([xshift=10pt]frame.west) - ([xshift=-10pt]segmentation.center) $ )
                        in
                        ([yshift=-{0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                          edge[line width={\RuleFactor*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}] 
                        ([yshift={0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                        ([xshift=-{0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                          edge[line width={\RuleFactor*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}] 
                        ([xshift={0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                        ;
                        }{}  
\IfEq{#2}{minus}{%
                    \path[line width=6pt,mp,draw]
                        let \p1 = ( $ ([yshift=-5pt]xl|-frame.north) - ([yshift=5pt]xl|-frame.south) $ ),
                              \p2 = ( $ ([xshift=10pt]frame.west) - ([xshift=-10pt]segmentation.center) $ )
                        in 
                        ([xshift=-{0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                          edge[line width={\RuleFactor*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}] 
                        ([xshift={0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                        ;
                        }{}
\IfEq{#2}{equal}{%
                    \path[line width=6pt,mp,draw]
                        let \p1 = ( $ ([yshift=-5pt]xl|-frame.north) - ([yshift=5pt]xl|-frame.south) $ ),
                              \p2 = ( $ ([xshift=10pt]frame.west) - ([xshift=-10pt]segmentation.center) $ )
                        in 
                        ([xshift=-{0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))},yshift={0.12*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                          edge[line width={\RuleFactor*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}] 
                        ([xshift={0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))},yshift={0.12*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                        ([xshift=-{0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))},yshift=-{0.12*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                          edge[line width={\RuleFactor*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}] 
                        ([xshift={0.5*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))},yshift=-{0.12*min(veclen(\x1,\y1),veclen(\x2,\y2))}]xl) 
                        ;
                        }{}
}

\newcommand{\doibs}[3]{\scantokens{%
            \begin{tcolorbox}[   
                    colback=white,
                    arc=10pt,
                    colframe=black,
                    freelance,
                    sidebyside,
                    sidebyside align=top,
                    frame code=\bround,
                    segmentation code=\sep,
                    interior code=\ds{#3}
            ]
            \raggedright #1 \tcblower \raggedright #2
            \end{tcolorbox}}}

\begin{document}

\doibs{A\\A\\A\\A}{B}{pm}

\doibs{A\\A\\A\\A}{B}{me}

\doibs{A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A}{B}{pe}

\doibs{A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A}{B}{ep}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### First version:

Here's one possibility (see remarks below):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{mp}{RGB}{240,240,240} 

\newcommand{\bround}{
                    \draw[rounded corners=15pt,color=mp,line width=1pt,fill=white]
                        (frame.south west) -- 
                        (frame.north west) -- 
                        (frame.north east) --
                        (frame.south east) -- cycle;
}
\newcommand{\sep}{
                    \draw[color=mp,line width=1pt]
                    ([yshift=10pt]segmentation.south) -- ([yshift=-10pt]segmentation.north);
}

\newcommand{\ds}[1]{
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
                {pp}{\dosign{0.25}{plus}\dosign{0.75}{plus}}%
                {pm}{\dosign{0.25}{plus}\dosign{0.75}{minus}}%
                {pe}{\dosign{0.25}{plus}\dosign{0.75}{equal}}%
                {mp}{\dosign{0.25}{minus}\dosign{0.75}{plus}}%
                {mm}{\dosign{0.25}{minus}\dosign{0.75}{minus}}%
                {me}{\dosign{0.25}{minus}\dosign{0.75}{equal}}%
                {ep}{\dosign{0.25}{equal}\dosign{0.75}{plus}}%
                {em}{\dosign{0.25}{equal}\dosign{0.75}{minus}}%
                {ee}{\dosign{0.25}{equal}\dosign{0.75}{equal}}%
    }[\PackageError{ds}{Undefined option to ds: #1}{}]%
}

\newcommand{\dosign}[2]{aaa
                    \coordinate (xl) at ($ (frame.west)!#1!(frame.east) $ ); 
\IfEq{#2}{plus}{%
                    \path[mp,draw]
                        let \p1 = ( $ ([yshift=-5pt]xl|-frame.north) - ([yshift=5pt]xl|-frame.south) $ )
                        in 
                        ([yshift=-5pt]xl|-frame.north) 
                          edge[line width={0.12*veclen(\x1,\y1)}] 
                        ([yshift=5pt]xl|-frame.south)
                        ([xshift=-{0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]xl) 
                          edge[line width={0.12*veclen(\x1,\y1)}] 
                        ([xshift={0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]xl)
                        ;
                        }{}  
\IfEq{#2}{minus}{%
                    \path[line width=6pt,mp,draw]
                        let \p1 = ( $ ([yshift=-5pt]xl|-frame.north) - ([yshift=5pt]xl|-frame.south) $ )
                        in 
                        ([xshift=-{0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]xl)
                          edge[line width={0.12*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]
                        ([xshift={0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]xl) 
                        ;
                        }{}
\IfEq{#2}{equal}{%
                    \path[line width=6pt,mp,draw]
                        let \p1 = ( $ ([yshift=-5pt]xl|-frame.north) - ([yshift=5pt]xl|-frame.south) $ )
                        in 
                        ([xshift=-{0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)},yshift={0.1*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]xl)
                          edge[line width={0.12*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]
                        ([xshift={0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)},yshift={0.1*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]xl) 
                        ([xshift=-{0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)},yshift=-{0.1*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]xl)
                          edge[line width={0.12*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]
                        ([xshift={0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)},yshift=-{0.1*veclen(\x1,\y1)}]xl) 
                        ;
                        }{}
}

\newcommand{\doibs}[3]{\scantokens{%
            \begin{tcolorbox}[   
                    colback=white,
                    arc=10pt,
                    colframe=black,
                    freelance,
                    sidebyside,
                    sidebyside align=top,
                    frame code=\bround,
                    segmentation code=\sep,
                    interior code=\ds{#3}
            ]
            \raggedright #1 \tcblower \raggedright #2
            \end{tcolorbox}}}

\begin{document}

\doibs{A\\A\\A\\A}{B}{pp}

\doibs{A}{B}{me}

\doibs{A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A\\A}{B}{pe}

\doibs{A\\A\\A}{B}{ep}

\doibs{A\\A}{B}{ee}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks

1. The size of the shapes and the line width will adjust automatically depending on the height of the box.
2. Notice that now `\dosign` has just two mandatory arguments (instead of the original nine arguments) and that `\doibs` has only three arguments.
3. The third argument for `\doibs` is used to decide which symbols to draw; I implemented nine combinations for "plus" (`p`), "minus" (`m`) and "equal"  (`e`). For example using `me` in the third argument means draw "minus" sign to the left and "equal" sign to the right; using `pm` in the third argument means draw "plus" sign to the left and "minus" sign to the right.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I wanted to achieve. When I follow your source code I will have to build a macro for every box (+-,--,++,-+,=+,+=, etc) and that's what I wanted to prevent by creating `\ds` and `\dosign`. Isn't there any way to get the height out of the `tcolorbox-environment`?

Comment: @Moldevort please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Moldevort I've updated my answer with a new version that might be of interest for you.

Comment: The `freelance` option is deprecated since version 3.00 of `tcolorbox`, as mentioned in the latest [Package Documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) (version 3.05 2014-05-28). The key can simply be removed in @Gonzalo's elaborate answer.